Alternative approach: $A, B \in (C): x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $OAB$ is a right triangle at $O.$ Find min and max of $P= MA \cdot MB,$ with $M(0; 3).$

$A$ and $B$ are two points on the circle centered at $O$ with a radius of $1,$ and $OAB$ is  a right triangle at $O.$ Consider $M(0;3).$ Find the min and max of $P = MA \cdot MB.$

I needed to find the max and min of $P = MA \cdot MB.$ Below is what I did. However, since this is a multiple-choice question, I wondered if a faster method exists.

Let $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ be the angle between $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{Ox}.$ Then $A = (\cos\theta; \sin\theta), B = (-\sin\theta; \cos\theta).$
$\implies \vec{AM} = (-\cos\theta; 3 - \sin\theta)$ and $\vec{BM} = (\sin\theta; 3- \cos\theta)$
$\implies P = AM \cdot BM = \sqrt{\cos^2\theta + (3 - \sin\theta)^2} \cdot \sqrt{\sin^2\theta + (3 - \cos\theta)^2} = \sqrt{(10 - 6\sin\theta)(10 - 6\cos\theta)}$
$= \sqrt{18u^2 -60u + 82} = \sqrt{f(u)},$ with $u = \sin\theta +\cos\theta \in [-\sqrt{2}; \sqrt{2}]$
The function $f(u)$ is decreasing monotone on its domain, so $P_{max} = \sqrt{f(-\sqrt{2})}$ and $P_{min} = \sqrt{f(\sqrt{2})}.$

Thank you!


I think you lost the term $36\sin \theta \cos \theta$ when you applied $u$ substitution

@Vasili Please check again. I used $u= \sin\theta + \cos\theta,$ so $36\sin\theta\cos\theta = 18(u^2 -1).$
